# Search API View exclude nodes with same Value(duplicates)

Tags: views, search

I am trying to create a view with the search API(indexed node view).

My English is not so good so I have to describe the structure and what I want as result:

The node has 2 important fields for this question. lets call them field a and field b.

Based on nodes with this fieldvalues:

- a: example1 b: 22
- a: example1 b: 13
- a: example1 b: 27
- a: example2 b: 26
- a: example2 b: 18
- a: example2 b: 4
- a: example3 b: 89
- a: example3 b: 16
- a: example3 b: 29

I want the result of the view like this:

- a: example1 b: 13
- a: example2 b: 4
- a: example3 b: 16

How can I can tell the view to show only 1 node per value A with the lowest value b?